# Conditional between a Promise and non-Promise

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to condense the following code example to avoid duplicating a large chuck of code WITHOUT creating an auxiliary `function` and WITHOUT using `await` (causes issues with `addListener`)?

```js
if (e.originUrl.startsWith('about:')) {
  browser.tabs.create({url, ....}) ...
  // more code
}
else {
  browser.tabs.get(e.tabId)                            
  .then(tab => {
    browser.tabs.create({url, ....}) ...
    // more code  
  });  
}
```

Update:
Reply by **derpirscher** is the solution I was looking for. It may not be as elegant as an auxiliary function, but the intent of the question was to find this solution. I wish everyone would demonstrate the same care as **derpirscher** has shown, when replying/commenting/marking a question.

Comment: You're pretty much ruled out the two possible solutions…

Comment: My question was, is it possible? the answer would be yes (with code), or no. What is the point of marking down a question?!

Comment: @erosman the question doesn't meet the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines, since it's not stating a problem and there's not an expected output. Try asking on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). By the way the answer is no, the purpose of functions is to avoid code repetition, if you don't want to define a new function, then you have to stick with copy/paste

Comment: @CristianTraìna The question was meant to find a solutions. I was not aware that there is no solution, and that should not invalidate a genuinely asked question.

Comment: You may want to detail what the issue with `await` is exactly, since that would be the most elegant solution. Instead of ruling out obvious solutions which you already know about, tell us why they're not suitable for you.

Comment: @erosman probably derpischer was better than us at understanding the question, because it sounded like "I don't want to repeat the code without using functions". Anyway, don't take downvotes personally :) they're just a score to highlight more interesting questions, not a judgement on you as a developer. I'm not among the ones that downvoted, but similar questions receive similar feedbacks, nothing personal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you don't seem to use the `tab` variable (if you do, expand your `...` and `// more code`) you could (doesn't mean you should) do something like the following

```
new Promise(res => {
  if (e.originUrl.startsWith('about:')) 
    return res();
  browser.tabs.get(e.tabId)
    .then(tab => res(tab));
})
.then((tab) => {
  browser.tabs.create({url, ....}) ...

  if (tab) {  //tab may be undefined 
    ..
  }
  // more code
})
```

But IMHO it would still be better to create an additional function where you do

```
function createTabWithMoreCode() {
  browser.tabs.create({url, ....}) ...
  // more code
}
```

and call it wherever you need it.

**EDIT**

As for your comment, if you need the `tab`, you can also resolve the promise using it. Just make sure, you check for existence when you access it in your `//more code`.

Comment: Thank you **derpirscher**. That is what I was looking for. It may not be as elegant as an auxiliary function, but I wanted to find out how it could be done. I wish everyone would demonstrate the same care as you have shown, when replying/commenting/marking a question.

Comment: Just for information, I do need the `tab` as I need to get `tab.active` when creating a new tab but only is some cases and hence the conditional.